# Sleuth + Zipkins with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-cloud, spring-data-elasticsearch, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

Can anyone point me towards the required/working configuration to use Elasticsearch as a storage type with Zipkins with Sleuth?

pom.xml

'

```
<description>Spring Boot Zipkin Server</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip>
    <zipkin.version>1.6.0</zipkin.version>
    <elasticsearch.version>2.3.4</elasticsearch.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- EXAMPLE FOR RABBIT BINDING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>demo-zipkin-server</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

application.yml

`server:
  port: 9411
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: ${RABBIT_HOST:localhost}
eureka:
 client:
  register-with-eureka: true
  service-url:
   defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
zipkin:
 self-tracing:
  enabled: false
  storage:
    type: elasticsearch
    elasticsearch:
      cluster: ${ES_CLUSTER:elasticsearch}
      hosts: ${ES_HOSTS:localhost:9300}
      index: ${ES_INDEX:zipkin}
      index-shards: ${ES_INDEX_SHARDS:5}
      index-replicas: ${ES_INDEX_REPLICAS:1}`

Application doesn't start up with these config. It throws 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.inboundMappe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classpath problems like you've posted are version-specific. Please update to most recent versions of dependencies.

For example, you can start with a base project using start.spring.io or otherwise to get something with recent deps. You could also copy a project like this:

https://github.com/openzipkin/sleuth-webmvc-example

Zipkin currently has native support for elasticsearch (meaning it does not use the Elasticsearch driver). So, the dependency to automatically configure this is:

```
<!-- override sleuth's zipkin version since we are using latest -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin</artifactId>
    <version>1.28.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- add the dependency for elasticsearch via http -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-elasticsearch-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.28.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Minimally set zipkin.storage.type=elasticsearch. Then, set you are [overriding](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/1.28.1/zipkin-server/src/main/resources/zipkin-server-shared.yml#L90) taking note that elasticsearch's http port is 9200 not 9300

Finally, please upvote native RabbitMQ support in zipkin so you don't need to do any of this! https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/1614

Comment: Thanks Adrian for the information and raising this point to be addressed. The suggested configuration has resolved the compilation issue but Zipkins is still not working with ES.

Can you please point to any working sample with ES?

Answer (score 0):

Use spring cloud stream collector http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_spring_cloud_sleuth_stream_zipkin_collector with an elasticsearch data store https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/zipkin-server/README.md#elasticsearch-storage

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. But, I have already gone through it and it didn't helped.  Attaching my config in the question.